# Installing GMP on macOS High SIerra via Homebrew

Tags: php, composer-php, gmp

I have been trying to get this running on my machine: https://github.com/Minishlink/web-push-php-example

After creating the project and changing into the directory `composer install` returned this:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

The problems it then lists all look close to this:

```
the requested PHP extension gmp is missing from your system.
```

So I installed gmp via Homebrew.

Searching for gmp afterwards returned this:

```
==> Searching local taps...
gmp ✔
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
==> Searching blacklisted, migrated and deleted formulae...
```

But if I check the list, that is returned by `php -m` it is not there.

I also tried adding the extension via `extension=gmp.so` to the php.ini which resulted in new errors.

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_gmp.so'
```

And of course I still get the same errors when trying `composer install` in my project directory.

Please help me out! I don't know what to do...

Answer (score 5):

These steps helped me resolve this issue. Install php version

```
brew install php@7.1
```

add php path to ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc :

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/bin:$PATH"
```

then source file, start php and check gmp has been loaded

```
brew services start php@7.1
source ~/.zshrc
php -info | grep "GMP"
```

try again

```
composer install
```

Comment: Dude! Thank you very much. I have been trying to add GMP extension for the last 6 hours through Homebrew. This solution helped me.
Catch was to start the brew php service :P

Answer (score 1):

Try `brew upgrade php@7.1`. Once complete, restart the built-in PHP in Laravel